# How to join array values surrounded by tags in nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

Code for example:

```
{% set sites = [
    {name:"StackOverFlow",url:"https://stackoverflow.com/"},
    {name:"ask-Ubuntu",url:"https://askubuntu.com/"}
] %}
{% for site in sites %}
    <a href="{{site.url}}">{{site.name}}</a>, 
{% endfor %}
```

The result will look like:
[StackOverFlow](http://example.com), [ask-Ubuntu](http://example.com),

My question is how to prevent the unnecessary `,` in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loop.last` - boolean indicating the last iteration ([docs](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for))

```
{% set sites = [
    {name:"StackOverFlow",url:"https://stackoverflow.com/"},
    {name:"ask-Ubuntu",url:"https://askubuntu.com/"}
] %}
{% for site in sites %}
    <a href="{{site.url}}">{{site.name}}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{ ',' if not loop.last }}` a little bit shorter.